# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse touchpad isn't responding

Tags: mouse, elementary-os, touchpad

My computer shut down when the battery was depleted and before I could plug it in and since restarting it, the touchpad doesn't respond if I move my finger on it. The buttons do.

xinput is able to recognize the device and the button clicks but nothing happens when I move my finger. The pointer remains static and the terminal doesn't show any changes in output.

```
$ xinput --test 12
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   1 
button press   3 
button release 3 
button press   3 
button release 3 

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device                 id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

id=12 is my touchpad while the wireless device must be my wireless mouse. I double checked the mouse settings and all looks fine. How did I fix this error with my touchpad?

EDIT: 
This disables the device but setting the property to 1 again doesn't reset the touchpad.

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a similar problem, also using 14.04. xinput list command was showing the touchpad on the list but it was not responding. I resolved it by changing the mouse & touchpad settings. Go to System Tools -> Preference -> Mouse & Touchpad (NB: Using gnome-flashback hence I have a menu, if on unity just go to the systems settings)

[image]

Ensure the touchpad is on and other settings that you want e.g. tap to click